# Why does .Net DataTable.PrimaryKey ignore changes to column sequence?

Tags: .net, vb.net, datatable, primary-key

I define a DataTable with a PrimaryKey of {Key1, Key2} (actually it's predefined; I have no say in it). I then want to change it to {Key2, Key1} but it doesn't; it's still {Key1, Key2}. Note I can change to {Key3, key1} and then {Key2, Key1} and that works, but of course only if Key3, Key1 is unique. A sample Unit Test ...

```
    <TestMethod()> Public Sub THC0841A_DS_AddPrimaryKey_Multi_Change()
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    Assert.AreEqual(True, ds.EnforceConstraints)
    Dim dt As New DataTable("MyTable"), dr As DataRow
    ds.Tables.Add(dt)
    dt.Columns.Add("Key1", GetType(String))
    dt.Columns.Add("Key2", GetType(Decimal))
    dt.Columns.Add("Value", GetType(String))
    dt.Rows.Add("A", 11D, "A-11-V")
    dr = dt.Rows.Add({"A", 22D, "A-22-V"})

    dt.PrimaryKey = {dt.Columns("Key1"), dt.Columns("Key2")}
    Assert.AreEqual("Key1,Key2", String.Join(",", From item In dt.PrimaryKey Select $"{item.ColumnName}"))

    dt.Rows.Add("E", 9D, "E-9-V")

    'now change PK
    Assert.AreEqual("Key1,Key2", String.Join(",", From item In dt.PrimaryKey Select $"{item.ColumnName}"))
    dt.PrimaryKey = {dt.Columns("Key2"), dt.Columns("Key1")}
    Assert.AreEqual("Key2,Key1", String.Join(",", from item In dt.PrimaryKey Select $"{item.ColumnName}"), "NO! this fails!")
    dt.PrimaryKey = {dt.Columns("Value"), dt.Columns("Key1")}
    Assert.AreEqual("Value,Key1", String.Join(",", From item In dt.PrimaryKey Select $"{item.ColumnName}"))
    dt.PrimaryKey = {dt.Columns("Key2"), dt.Columns("Key1")}
    Assert.AreEqual("Key2,Key1", String.Join(",", From item In dt.PrimaryKey Select $"{item.ColumnName}"))
End Sub
```

## EDIT

Oh dear; I was hoping to keep this simple, rather than venture into the philosophical "sets aren't ordered" and "swapping order of keys would have no impact". Just because MS can't do MVC properly is no reason to say that the Model isn't broken when the View uses the Model's properties.
You see, a DataTable has a DefaultView property, and a DataView has an ApplyDefaultSort property, which allows you to view the data in .. (drum roll) .. Primary Key (PK) order! This is great for users viewing say a customer address list when you can view it by customer. Saying that the customer address list is a set of information with no sequence is ludicrous ("Give me all the first line of addresses by customer, then all the second line of addresses by customer"). I am actually wanting to compare two datasets and display non-matching PKs. The ordering of the PKs in the original datasets was created by people who, like some people here, firmly believe that the order of columns in a primary key is irrelevant; getting a list of mis-matching addresses for customers but sorted by address line type is not helpful, so I want to swap the PK into CustomerID first. Aha! Someone might say, just delete the PK and redefine it. No, that breaks the FK relationships in the DataSets.

Comment: I would imagine that you're not seeing a change because such a change would have no impact, so the underlying code chooses not to do useless work. The primary key just specifies a combination of columns that must be unique. The order that you specify those columns is irrelevant, so why should the `DataTable` go to the trouble of changing the `PrimaryKey` property value and also checking that every row has a unique combination of values when it knows that they all must have?

Comment: Yeah, *conceptually*, the primary key is a logical construct which is a *set* of columns. Sets don't really have orders.

Comment: Yes, it can be argued that DataSets are intrinsically unordered. No, I will not accept that DefaultDataView is intrinsically unordered, which has an ApplyDefaultSort (by PK) property. I have edited my original question to point this out. BTW it isn't helped by MS IDE DataSet GUI design not allowing the PK column sequence to be specified or changed (obviously designed by Computer Science types than Real World types).